# Is it mandatory to integrate RESTEasy with Spring on JBOSS AS?

Tags: java, spring, rest, jboss7.x, resteasy

I am trying to expose a simple web resource on JBOSS AS using Spring.

Is it mandatory to configure RESTEasy with Spring in order to the server to serve the requests correctly?

I have already deployed my war file without no configuration in the web.xml and I don't know if the configuration has something to do with RESTEasy integration.

All the documentation found indicates so but I need to be sure if it can't be done without RESTEasy.

Comment: No, not at all. I successfully used Resteasy for a long time hosted on Tomcat and with guice dependency injection. However, I must warn you the documentation never really worked. I always had to do something more with the Web.xml to make it work, and that changed from version to version. I swapped it for Play, but tbh it was fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to access Spring beans in your REST endpoint classes, then you have to integrate Spring with RestEasy, so that RestEasy is able to find your Spring beans. If you don't have this requirement, then it's not necessary.